# Python monitoring progress of Handbrake

Tags: python, subprocess, progress-bar, handbrake

So I am using handbrake and python to encode videos based on a schedule. I need to monitor the progress because I use it to estimate the encoding time. Then I can fit it to my scheduler.

I am having an issue getting the ETA and % complete from the process. Here is what I have so far

```
profile = ["HandBrakeCLI","-i",input,"-o","output","-e","x264"]
cp = subprocess.Popen(profile, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(cp.stderr.readline, b''):

  # regex match for % complete and ETA
  matches = re.match( r'.*(\d+\.\d+)\s%.*ETA\s(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s', line.decode('utf-8') )

  if matches:
    print( matches.group() )

  print(line),

cp.stderr.close()
cp.wait()
```

It does not match, in fact I'm not entirely sure what is going on. When I run my script, I see the ETA and % complete print out

```
Encoding: task 1 of 1, 1.19 % (45.57 fps, avg 62.74 fps, ETA 00h08m01s)
```

I've tried using stdout but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is that Handbrake CLI doesn't output new additional lines each time the process has progressed a bit, rather it modifies the existing line. Try printing the line immediately after `for line in inter..` and see what it actually gives you.

Comment: wouldn't that give me the output after the for loop exits? so when the process has finished ? I would like to get the information as the process is going.

Comment: First of all, you're iterating over stderr, maybe you need to iterate over stdout. Second,I think that cp.stderr.readline would return complete lines from the subprocess itself, not a single repeatedly updated line. I would print the last line after the `handbreak` process finishes, to see how it look. And, as I told you, I'd print each and every lines in the for loop, to understand what I actually receive.

Comment: iterating over stdout doesn't print out the Encoding information. I do not understand what you mean, can you provide an example?

Comment: Try remove lines 5-13 and instead, just output `print(line)`, and let me know when and what it actually prints.

Comment: Here is the output in a pastebin (http://pastebin.com/SLuayW3q). essentially its one line with "Encoding: task 1 of 1, 98.04 % (394.61 fps, avg 385.53 fps, ETA 00h00m01s)\r" repeating over and over until the % hits 100, then it terminates with \n

Comment: The issue (I think!) seems to be that \r (carriage return, return to the beginning of the line) isn't a line separator (\n), so readline reads the entire chunk until the last character \n appears, and you get it all as one chunk. 
A possible solution would be reading stderr byte by byte into a string, until you reach a \r character, and then treat that string as a single line. After that start again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read from stdout, not stderr.

```
profile = ["HandBrakeCLI","-i",input,"-o","output","-e","x264"]
cp = subprocess.Popen(profile, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, strout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(cp.stdout.readline, b''):

  # regex match for % complete and ETA
  matches = re.match( r'.*(\d+\.\d+)\s%.*ETA\s(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s', line.decode('utf-8') )

  if matches:
    print( matches.group() )

  print(line),

cp.stderr.close()
cp.stdout.close()
cp.wait()
```

Using a progress wrapper (using clint.textui.progress.Bar) and read byte by  byte (works for me):

```
profile = ["HandBrakeCLI","-i",input,"-o","output","-e","x264"]
cp = subprocess.Popen(profile, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, strout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
bar = Bar(label="Encoding %s" % input, width=30, expected_size=10000, every=1)
bar.show(0)

line = ""
c = 0

while True:    
  nl = cp.stdout.read(1)
  if nl == '' and cp.poll() is not None:
     break  # Aborted, no characters available, process died.
  if nl == "\n":
     line = ""
  elif nl == "\r":
     # regex match for % complete and ETA, assuming the regex is ok.
     matches = re.match( r'.*(\d+\.\d+)\s%.*ETA\s(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s', line.decode('utf-8') )

     if matches:
        print( matches.group() )
        # do something
     line = ""
  else:
     line += nl

error = cp.stderr.read()
success = "Encode done!" in error
```

Did not test the code, rewrote it to match the threads initial post.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

There are good bones here. However, I had to make a few modification to make it work with Python 3.7 and PyQt5. The ui lines are for a PyQt5 QProgressBar and a QLineEdit

This code has been tested.  I thank all of you for your help.

def hbConvertISOtoMP4():

```
line = ""
inFile = #place your input file here!
oFile =  #place your output file here!

ui.progressBar.setValue(0)
profile = ["HandBrakeCLI", "-t", "1", "-i", inFile, "-o", oFile, "-e", "x264"]
cp = Popen(profile, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True)

ui.leProgress.setText('Loading data... Please Wait.')
ui.centralwidget.repaint()

while True:
    nl = cp.stdout.read(1)

    if nl == '' or cp.poll() is not None:
        break  # Aborted, no characters available, process died.

    elif nl.hex() == '0d' and len(line) > 30:

        # regex match for % complete and ETA, assuming the regex is ok.
        matches = re.match(r'.*(\d+\.\d+)\s%.*ETA\s(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s\)', line)

        if matches:
            # do something here
            # I inserted this code for a PyQt5 Progress Bar UI
            ui.leProgress.setText(line)
            ui.centralwidget.repaint()
            pBar = matches.group().split(' ')
            ui.progressBar.setValue(int(float(pBar[5])))

        line = ""
    else:
        line += nl.decode('utf-8')

error = cp.stderr.read()

if 'Encode done!' in str(error):
    ui.progressBar.setValue(0)
    ui.leProgress.setText("Encode Done!")
else:
    ui.leProgress.setText('Error during Endoding')
```